# opcache_reset() keeps returning false

Tags: php-fpm, opcache

I have a web server running WordPress on Nginx and PHP-FPM (PHP 8.0).

When a PHP file is changed, it will be detected by a separate program and [`opcache_reset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.opcache-reset.php) is called repeatedly until it succeeds. Since `opcache_reset()` doesn't work on CLI, it is called via FastCGI interface.

Sometimes, `opcache_reset()` keeps returning `false` for several seconds. And in the worst case, it keeps indefinitely. In such a case, a PHP-FPM process is waiting for the `opcache_reset()` to succeed.

When `opcache_reset()` returns `false`, [`opcache_get_status()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.opcache-get-status.php) returns value containing `'restart_pending' => true`.

It seems there's a resource contention and it causes deadlock in some circumstances. What resource is causing this problem?

Environment:

```
$ uname -r
5.10.197-186.748.amzn2.x86_64

$ php -v
PHP 8.0.30 (cli) (built: Aug 24 2023 20:32:30) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.30, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.30, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```